# Finding mean given information

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Given that 95% of the values is between 20 and 34, what would be the mean? I think it's 27..but I'm not sure..if it's not 27, what's the right way to solve it? Please explain this to me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is in general no way to know the mean when you only know 95% of the data.

You've used the `normal-distribution` tag. Do your values follow a normal distribution? If they do and you know where those 95% of the values are found (for example whether they are the lowest 95%, or the middle 95%, or the highest 95%), you could use a [standard normal table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) to find the mean.

Answer (score 0):

The question is poorly worded. It doesn't ask what it (probably) intends to ask. If your data comes from a normal distribution, and the *middle* 95% of the values lie between 20 and 34, then, by symmetry, the mean must be at 27, as you say. If the question is from a beginning course on statistics, that's probably the answer they're expecting.

But, there is another way to interpret the question. It's possible (I don't know for sure) that you could have a normal distribution with (for example) 2% of its "tail" to the left of 20, and 3% of its other "tail" to the right of 34. This distribution would still have 95% of its values between 20 and 34, but its mean would not be 27. This is a much harder question, and is probably not what was intended.